# Why T::fn2 has only one parameter when it was called with two arguments?

Tags: perl

I have next script:

```perl
package T;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub fn1 {
    my( $var1, $var2 ) =  @_;
    T::fn2 $var1, $var2;
}

sub fn2 {
    print ">>@_<<"; # >>x1<<
}

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;

T::fn1 'x1', 'x2'; # >>x1<<
```

Here `T::fn2` is called with two arguments but it get only one parameter.

I understand that I call forward subroutine which is not visible at time of parsing and is counted as bareword.

But I have `use strict`, `use warnings` so I expect warning is issued or program should not work at all instead it works incorrectly.

So **Why it is still working and `T::fn2` is called actually with one argument?**

perl version is 5.30.3

Comment: You can only omit parens around a parameter list for declared subs.

Comment: @ikegami: or when forward declared ;-)

Comment: Since when is a forward declaration not a declaration? My comments stands on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p
```

to see how the compiler understands the code:

```perl
sub fn1 {
    (my($var1, $var2) = @_);
    ($var1->T::fn2, $var2);
}
```

So, the **call is interpreted as the indirect object notation of a method call**, and the subroutine returns two values: the result of the method call and `$var2`.

---

To make it work correctly you have two choices:

1. Use parentheses around subroutine arguments

   T::fn2($var1, $var2);
2. Make sure the function is declared before it's called

```perl
sub fn2 {
    print ">>@_<<";
}

sub fn1 {
    my ($var1, $var2) =  @_;
    T::fn2 $var1, $var2;
}
```

3. Make sure the function is declared before it's called (forward declaration)

```perl
sub fn2;

sub fn1 {
    my ($var1, $var2) =  @_;
    T::fn2 $var1, $var2;
}

sub fn2 {
    print ">>@_<<";
}
```

Comment: It is a little bit odd that the code accepts `$var1` as a legitimate object, however. As in `new FOO` should become `FOO->new`, but here it is a string.

Comment: `method $obj` works, too. Indirect object notation should be banned!

Comment: @choroba, [`no indirect;`](https://metacpan.org/pod/indirect)

Comment: @ikegami: I know. But it should be the default :-)

Comment: @choroba Backwards compat. But it was suppose to be on --uh, off-- by default in Perl 7